# Cleaning up git history after pull/push and branch without conflicts

Tags: git, rebase

How can I restore linear history after a change was made then a pull (without conflict) then commit/push (which creates an artificial branch and a merge).

Several people are working on the same branch but in separate files/folders. Prior to committing, git will sometime indicate that some changes have to be pulled from the repository before commit can be done. After a successful pull without conflicts, the new code is committed and pushed. However, the git history now looks something like that:

[image: git tree with branches]

I would expect the history to be linear as there were no conflicts in the merge. After doing some reading, I understand that if there are no conflicts, I should do a fetch and then a rebase to get a linear history. But the deed is done. How can I restore linear history?

[image: git tree linear]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git rebase` can work. Assume the current branch is `master`, and the commits in your first graph are labeled from the bottom to the top. The first 4 green are A B C D, the next 5 purple are E F G H I, the left 2 green are J K, the right 2 purple are L M and the top green is N.

```
git rebase --onto J D master
```

And we get a linear history `A-B-C-D-J-E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-L'-M'`. `E'` and `E` are equivalent commits that have different sha1.

There is another way

```
git rebase --onto I D master
```

And we get a linear history `A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J'-L'-M'`.

If `git rebase` is not so clear, it can also be done via `git reset` and `git cherry-pick`, the former to cut and the latter to transplant.

Since K and N are merge commits, they are not supposed to exist in the linear history. We could just ignore them.

```
git reset J --hard
git cherry-pick E F G H I L M
#or one by one: git cherry-pick E;git cherry-pick F;...
```

Finally we get the linear history `A-B-C-D-J-E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-L'-M'`.

Or in another way

```
git reset I --hard
git cherry-pick J L M
```

And we get the linear history `A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J'-L'-M'`. If there is no conflict, the two trees have the same contents.

Answer (score 1):

A `merge` (`pull` without according configuration or parameters is equal to `fetch`+`merge`, you can make `pull` equal to `fetch`+`rebase` though if you want or do those commands manually) will **only** maintain a linear history if the merge is fast-forward, meaning there are no commits unique to the branch you are merging into. You can also tell `merge` to only do the merge if it is a fast-forward merge or tell it to never keep linear history, but to always create a merge commit.

A `rebase` will **always** maintain a linear history.

Whether there are conflicts or not does not influence history-linearness in any way.

The decision whether you use `merge` or `rebase` if you want as linear history as possible is relatively simple.

If the target branch of your operation is a local branch, meaning none of the unique commits on it are pushed yet, you can safely do a `rebase`, as it will only affect your local history.

If the target branch of your operation already got pushed, i. e. has unique commits that already got pushed and thus eventually were fetched by others already, you should use `merge` and live with the non-linear history, because all your colleagues would hate you, as each and every one would have to construct a non-obvious rebase if they already pulled in those commits you rebase.

The same is true for your current situation, as I understood you already pushed your merged changes, this means if you change it to linear history, you will change published history and all your colleagues will have to rebase their work after you force-pushed your changed history.

If you did not push already or don't care about the wave of hatred that will hit you, you can do it easily with rebasing. If you e. g. are ok with having the 5th green commit from bottom on top of all the velvet commits, you can simply checkout your green branch and do `git rebase pink` and you will end up with a linear history.